# Writing to Embedded Resources

Tags: c#, vb.net, console-application, .net-assembly, embedded-resource

I have an application in which there is an XML file which needs to be hidden from the client. I included it in the project as an Embedded Resource, but I need to be able to modify it when my application executes, and from what I've read, you cannot do that with an Embedded resource.

Is there any other way to embed an XML file into the application, but to still be able to read and modify it when the application is running?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to change resources for an assembly that's running, since executing code is locked read-only by the OS. The whole point of using resources is so that they are inaccessible from outside the app at run time. It is not possible to embed/change them since they need to be recompiled.

Comment: Then do you know if there is another method to do that?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way.  It is possible to use the Framework to compile code at run time but I have no idea how it's done and I guarantee you that it is not something that beginners or probably even intermediate programmers should normally be doing.

Comment: I don't think so. When you select **Content** as build action it allows you to retrieve a file (in same dir as assembly) as a stream via `Application.GetContentStream( uri )`.